# Read CSV file from Azure Blob storage as a Snowpark Dataframe

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage

I have the following setup

Azure ML studio + Azure Blob Storage + Snowflake Data Warehouse. I want to read a CSV file as a Snowpark Dataframe without loading the data into memory. For example, we have the below code in pyspark. I want to replicate the same as a Snowpark Dataframe instead of a Pyspark Dataframe.

```
product_df = spark.read.csv('wasbs://XXXXXXXXXXXx.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/XXXXX/XXXXXXXX.csv',sep=',', header='true')
```

I tried establishing establishing snowflake connection using snowpark library and tried to use session.read.csv() similar to spark.read.csv. It didn't work as expected. It's asking for schema of the contents of csv file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't see any Snowpark solution where you read file from external location .                     
My thought, you can create external table on top of Azure Blob storage and access this external table using SQL using Snowpark and load data from external table in Snowpark dataframe.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro

Comment: You will need to create an external stage over that location in Snowflake first and also need to declare a Schema in advance if you want to read that as CSV.